# Grep pattern on Linux

Tags: linux, grep, aix

I want to grep a pattern which should include multiple lines as output. On AIX it works like this (I am using this for db2)

```
db2 list db directory | grep -p Indirect
```

but on Linux it won't do the same. Trying to do every possible flag, but no success.

Comment: can you give us sample input data for `db2 list db directory`?

Comment: The [`-p` flag in AIX grep](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/grep.htm) means "paragraph" mode; the closest you would get with GNU grep would be a wide `-C` flag, but that's imprecise. You'd probably want to implement something in awk to have it slurp paragraphs and print matching ones.

Comment: It's good, now. Tried an alternative solution db2 list db directory | grep -B 5 -A 3 Indirect. Thanks anyway